# Installing wordpress on Parallels plesk 9.5.3

Tags: installation

I would like to know if it is possible to install WP on Parallels Plesk 9.5.3, and if so, I do I do that?

Thanks,
Erez A.

Answer (score 1):

Plesk is administration helper software, it is not underlying web server stack (which really matters for WordPress).

Please see [Hosting WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress) in Codex for official technical requirements and recommendations.

Comment: I had the option to choose between Parallels Plesk and cPanel. I chose Parallels with no particular reason. When I had in the past cPanl' I installed WP through 'simple script'. Now, if I compare cPanel with Parallels, without taking the hosting into consideration (I know that the hosting can handle WP requirements), I thought to myself that the installation suppose to be the same or at least close to each other.

Comment: @Erez there can be some helper scripts to ease installation of packages like WP on hosting, however they often provide outdated versions or skip important configuration steps. It is always better to stick with [native WordPress installation procedure](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress).